# Do not return the name of the picture on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, delegation

I have a problem with the delegation `UIImagePickerController`, so I can only returns the path pictures - without information on the name of the image.

Here is the code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
     {
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
        NSURL *imagePath = [editingInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
        NSString *imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        NSLog(@"%@",localFilePath);
    }
    [self upload];
}
```

The application returns the following result:

> 2015-11-02 17:05:01.512 AppTest [903:300310] localFilePath./var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/39F58494-7645-4CA4-B96F-744257FE6AD3/Documents

The whole application runs on one ViewController.
Please help.

Comment: So the question is how to receive the name of a specific `UIImage`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What problem exactly are you having with the posted code?

Comment: Does not display the names of NSLog additional photos (imageName)

Comment: what does `NSLog(@"Path : %@  \n Name : %@", imagePath, imageName);` gives you ?

Comment: Is the image picker being used to take a photo with the camera or select an image from the photo library? `imagePath` will be `nil` when using the camera since camera photos don't exist on disk. They have no URL or name.

Comment: @maaetsoh - result: "Path : (null) 
 Name : (null)"

Comment: @rmaddy - I use the camera. Photos of the applications normally enroll on the phone.